# Buffer overflow quandary

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

So, I am trying to perform a buffer overflow on this code, with the purpose of changing the variable `target` to 'Y'.  The thing is, I can't seem to get the buffer to overflow enough to generate a runtime error.  Can anyone help me understand as to why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {SIZE = 50};

char target = 'Z';
char name[SIZE];
FILE *f;

void read(char *s) {
   char buffer[SIZE];
   int i = 0; 
   int c;

   for (;;) 
   {
      c = getchar();
      if ((c == EOF) || (c == '\n')) 
         break;
      buffer[i] = c;
      i++;
   }
   buffer[i] = '\0';

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
      s[i] = buffer[i];
}


int main(void) 
{
   read(name);

   if (strcmp(name, "ABCD") == 0) 
      target = 'Y';

   printf("%s\n", name);
   printf("%c\n", target);

   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What was your attempted input?

Comment: An extremely long string.  Thousands of characters.  It overflowed the buffer, all right, but it didn't cause a runtime error.  Which I'm guessing means that it didn't overwrite any return value.

Comment: How do you intend the attack to work - just overwriting `target` directly? Have you tried printing the addresses of `buffer` and `target` so you know how much data you need?

Comment: An overflow attack would usually attempt to overwrite the return address (which is much easier to reach from `buffer` as they're very close on the stack.

Comment: I get `*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated` for moderately long strings (~100 chars).

Comment: I thought the point of the overflow was always to overwrite the return address?  I plan to overwrite read's return address so that it just skips directly to the contents of the if statement.  Is that wrong?  How would you do it?  Is there a gdb command that will print a local var, like buffer?

Comment: You can't overwrite 'target' using long string, because 'target' isn't allocated on stack.

Comment: I'm using a vm, so I dont have to worry about things like that.  I just have my security turned off.

Comment: @alexander see the comment above yours.  I'm trying to overwrite a return address.

Comment: Note that your `for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) s[i] = buffer[i];` loop carefully doesn't overwrite `target`.  Also notice that if `target` is at a lower address in memory than `name`, you won't overwrite `target` even if you change the upper bound on the copy loop to the number of characters read.  You might well clobber `f`, though.  The `strcmp()` in the `main()` is…interesting; you'd have to type an ASCII NUL at the command line — which can be done, but isn't often done.  You'll usually have problems getting back to `main()` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 'non-crashing' version of your code, that does overwrite the bounds of the `name` array for modest sizes of input string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {SIZE = 50};

char target_1 = 'Z';
char name[SIZE] = "Help";
char target_2 = 'Z';

static void read(char *s)
{
   char buffer[2*SIZE];
   int i = 0; 
   int c;

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
      buffer[i++] = c;
   buffer[i] = '\0';

   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
      s[j] = buffer[j];
}


int main(void) 
{
   printf("Data-1: %c %s %c\n", target_1, name, target_2);
   read(name);
   printf("Data-2: %c %s %c\n", target_1, name, target_2);
   return(0);
}
```

Example runs:

```
$ for len in 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 ; do echo $len; perl -e "print 'a' x $len" | ./bo; done
48
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: Z aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Z
49
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: Z aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Z
50
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: Z aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaZ Z
51
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: a aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Z
52
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: a aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Z
53
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: a aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Z
54
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: a aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Z
$
```

You can see that the `target_1` is at a higher memory address than `name`, and that it does get overwritten from an input of size 52 or larger.

When I say 'non-crashing', I mean 'it does not crash for input lines that are long enough to overflow the `name` buffer but not so long as to overflow the `buffer` buffer' (roughly lengths 50 to 100).  Using longer input strings, the program crashes with a segmentation fault, but it is interesting that it crashes after printing the second line of output, rather than during the return from `read()`.

```
140
Data-1: Z Help Z
Data-2: a aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Z
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Tested on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks, with GCC 4.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this with a changed return address, you'll need to overwrite it with a specific address that you want. In this case for the desired result, you could overwrite with the address of the code `target = 'Y';`

Depending on how the stack is organized, you may be able to directly clobber the return address from `read()` that will return you to just after the first line of `main` where it is called. Failing that, you have the opportunity to clobber `i`, which will let you arbitrarily write to memory. You will need to be careful as you write these bytes, as it will affect your index.

I'm going to pretend this is being done on an ARM, as I'm more familiar with their stack layout and calling conventions. So, your stack my look like so:

```
STACKPTR-60: buffer[0]
 |   |   |
STACKPTR-11: buffer[49]
STACKPTR-10: padding
STACKPTR -9: padding
STACKPTR -8: i (bits 7..0)
 |   |   |
STACKPTR -5: i (bits 31..24)
STACKPTR -4: c (bits 7..0)
 |   |   |
STACKPTR -1: c (bits 31..24)
STACKPTR +0: link register (return address) (bits 7..0)
 |   |   |
STACKPTR +3: link register (return address) (bits 31..24)
```

So, with this stack layout, as you overflow `buffer`, you will first fill two pad bytes. After that, you fill the least significant byte of `i`. In this case, you can skip a huge overflow and just modify your index to point to the stacked link register. You want `i=60` to start writing to the return address, but after you write it, it will be incremented, so you really want `i=59`, which will then be incremented to `i=60`. At this point, you can then write the desired return address from least significant to most significant, followed by an `EOF` or `\n`.

**It is really important to note** that this is all incredibly architecture specific, and compiler specific. Compiler settings will determine the size of `int`s and whether the stack will be padded to align variables, and the order the variables appear on the stack. The architecture will determine what your stack frame will look like.

Comment: That's the thing; The nearest return address is the read function, and my string attack can't reach it.  Previous iterations of this problem that I've done have had {i} in the same place in the code {target}.  Why is the fact that i is now a local variable making this more difficult?

Comment: With `i` as a stack variable, your index is getting clobbered as you overflow. I missed that in the initial answer, so I'll update it.

Comment: Updated with an example using ARM's ABI.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  at the end of the input string, there is a 0xffffffff word, that, if tampered with at all, will end the input.  Can you think of a way around that?

Comment: In other words, i and buffer are in the wrong order for local variables.

Comment: As I noted, this is very architecture and compiler (and compiler settings) specific. You haven't given us any of that information. Your best bet is to look at the disassembly to see where all your stack variables have been placed.